# Use classes dependent of another class inside itself

Tags: c#, class

I wanted if there's a correct way of doing this:
I have an object that has some important information(public variables) inside it.
Then I have a class that does things with that important information the code would look something like this:

```
 public class Object
{
    public class DependantClass1;
    public class DependantClass2;

    public object ImportantVariable;
    public object ImportantVariable2;
    public object ImportantVariable3;
    public object ImportantVariable4;

    public Object()
    {
        DependantClass1 = new DependantClass1(this);
        DependantClass2 = new DependantClass1(this);
    }

}
```

The thing is, this "DependantClasses", work with many or all of the "ImportantVariables", so I think it's not worth to pass them all as arguments (in the real code would be many more variables).

This happens because I don't want to have all the code that works with the variables inside the "main" class, for the sake of modularity and ease when updating code.

I can't figure out a way of doing this some other way but it doesn't look right to me.

EDIT: The "DependantClasses" interact which each other, thats the main issue I think.

Comment: Could you refactor `DependantClass1/2` to take in an object of type `Object` instead? That way you'll have reference to the `DependantClass` so those fields won't be necessary in `Object`. If `DependantClass1/2` are not the same, you could have a `BaseDependantClass` that they both inherit from.

Comment: If what you mean by '"refactoring..."' is to pass a class 'Object'  as argument for the 'DependantClasses' I am. The second part I'm interested I'll look into that.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry you're right, had a brainfreeze for a second there. In that case, I don't see any reason to have the `DependantClass1` and `DependantClass2` fields there. Inheritance will depend on how closely linked they are, I'm just going by the name and seemingly similar functionality.

Comment: Sometimes the "Dependant Classes", will access other "Dependant Classes" throught the "Object" class. Also, they do completly different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend either creating an interface which contains all the `ImportantVariable`s, make your `Object` class implement that, and then make the `DependentClass`es take that interface in their constructors. **Or** (preferable in my opinion) abstract all the `ImportantVariable`s into a `VariableCollection` class (sure you could come up with a better name in your real app!) and make the `DependentClass`es take that class in instead.

### Method one (interface)

```
public interface IImportantVariables
{
  object ImportantVariable { get; } // I prefer exposing this 
                                    // kind of thing as a readonly 
                                    // property but it's up to you
  object ImportantVariable2 { get; }
  object ImportantVariable3 { get; }
  object ImportantVariable4 { get; }
}

public class Object : IImportantVariables
{
  // Implementation as before
}

public class DependentClass1 
{
  public DependentClass1(IImportantVariables variables)
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

### Method 2 (abstracted class)

```
public class ImportantVariables
{
  public object ImportantVariable;
  public object ImportantVariable2;
  public object ImportantVariable3;
  public object ImportantVariable4;
}

public class Object
{
  public class DependantClass1;
  public class DependantClass2;

  public ImportantVariables Variables;

  public Object()
  {
    Variables = new ImportantVariables();
    DependantClass1 = new DependantClass1(this.Variables);
    DependantClass2 = new DependantClass1(this.Variables);
  }
}
```

Comment: Doing this would be interesting but I realized something: `The "DependantClasses" interact which each other, thats the main issue`

Comment: Yes I think I would encapsulate the important variables in parameter object and then pass then pass that object around.   You could(should) add a synchronization object (lock) to the parameter block then the dependent classes could coordinate access to the parameter block.